# invisible layout controlled by menu button

Tags: android, menu, android-linearlayout

Can I control a horizontal linear layout by pressing the menu button on android? I basically want the layout to be invisible until the menu button on the phone is pressed which brings up the layout on the screen.

Thanks,

Ab

Comment: You really shouldn't be modifying the default functionality of the menu button in android. You're going to confuse your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [View stubs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html), that may do what you need. You can set the layout to invisible in xml, and in code where need make them visible.

Comment: can I have ImageViews in View stubs to hold images?

Comment: I havent tried it, used it only for linear layouts. But I dont see why we cant have them.